# ui controls for asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, user-interface, gridview

i have been using the basic toolkit that is provided with VS 2008

I am currently looking for UI control toolkit from third party.

I am basically concentrating on Gridview, treeview, textboxes, hoover, buttons and graphs(piecharts)

Order of preference:

1.) Totally free( can be used commercially no royalties)

2.) semi free ( can be used as trial version or has some sort of licience)

3.) paid (but not as expensive as terelik and all..)

Can any one suggest any thing..

thank you

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a shopping recommendation site. At the very least make this community wiki because it's not actually a real programming question. I suggest you read http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Best Free Controls for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361271/best-free-controls-for-net)
Also DevExpress claims to give away 60 components for free. Haven't tried it though. https://www.devexpress.com/Products/Free/NetOffer/
P.S. I agree with Kev. You should make this community wiki.